# How do I change a smoke collider's distance?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I've got smoke falling onto an object set with smoke collision physics, but as you can see from the screenshot, there is a gap between the smoke and the object. Where can I find the setting to change this to 0?

[image]

Comment: Could you upload your file to [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)? It's hard to guess what's going on without seeing all the settings